# create blocks programmtically on theme activation

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

I have got my theme set to where on activation pages are created and templates are set, how can I add gutenberg blocks?

***UPDATE:***

Doesn't create page and if I comment out the page_block_template function and make 'post_content' a empty string `' '` then it will create the page. So How do you do this, add blocks to a page template?

Function to add blocks to the page.

```
function page_block_template() {
    $pages_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'page' );
    $pages_type_object->template = array( 
        array( 'core/heading', array( 
            'level'         =>  '3',
            'className'     =>  'header',
            'content'       =>  ''
         ) ),
        array( 'core/separator', array( 
            'className' =>  'is-style-wide'
        ) ),
        array( 'core/paragraph', array( 
            'className' =>  'margin',
        ) ),

        array( 'core/list', array( 
            'className' =>  'list-unstyled h5',
            // STYLE <li class="list-inline-item"> ??

        ) ),

        array( 'core/heading', array( 
            'level'         =>  '3',
            'className'     =>  'header',
            'content'       =>  ''
         ) ),
        array( 'core/separator', array( 
            'className' =>  'is-style-wide'
        ) ),
     );
     $pages_type_object->template_lock = 'all';
}
add_action( 'init', 'page_block_template' );
```

Creates the page

```
if (isset($_GET['activated']) && is_admin()) {
    $page_title = 'Page';
    $page_content = page_block_template();
    $page_check = get_page_by_title($page_title);
    $page = array( 
        'post_type'     =>  'page',
        'post_title'    =>  $page_title,
        'post_content'  =>  $page_content,
        'post_status'   =>  'publish',
        'post_author'   =>  $user_id,
        'post_slug'     =>  'page'
    );
    if(!isset($page_check->ID) && !the_slug_exists('page')) {
        $page_id = wp_insert_post($page);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for Block Templates. This is a pretty good intro: https://www.billerickson.net/gutenberg-block-templates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use block templates this way. They are used only by Gutenberg on client side (JavaScript) when new post content is created. In your case you are creating page on server side (PHP). However you can create pages with initial block structure. Create new page manually and save it without adding any content (there will be only empty block structure as defined by your block template). Then get it's `post_content` value either from database using some DB client, or read and print it in some temporary PHP function. But you must get value exactly as stored in database. Use this text as string value for `post_content` in your page creation code.

This way you will have new page created with initial content matching your block template. Don't forget to change value if you change template structure.

Comment: then what about that link @michelle posted above?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that link. Block templates are great. You have already created one, and there is nothing wrong with your `page_block_template` function and you must keep it and hook it on `init` action, as you've already done. I'm just saying that you cannot create new posts/pages in PHP with block templates applied. Either create empty page (and get template mismatch message in block editor because your template is locked) or do as I described.

Comment: Is there an example somewhere on how to do this then?

Comment: After rereading your original post. It makes no sense! You contradict yourself many times.

Comment: What exactly doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: You start by saying that "You can't use block templates this way...:" then go on to say "... However you can create pages with initial block structure" which is what I did and you said right off that I can't use block templates that way. You give no examples of how to occumplish what I want even after me asking.

Comment: By "this way" I mean - you can't use block tempates to create initial content for new pages in **PHP** code. I'm not saying that you can't use block templates to create pages manually or that you can't create new pages in PHP with empty content. Your question was - how to add blocks to page, and by your example it is clear that you want to add these blocks in `post_content` during page creation in PHP. The answer is - you can't do that part. I described method how you can create this content matching your block template. There is no code example to show and I don't know any example links.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104101/discussion-between-bckelley-and-vitauts-stocka).